# Upload bytes or base64 string to s3 ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to s3 using the ruby aws sdk. I'm able to upload the base64 string if I don't set the content_type. If I do set the content_type to `image/png` the upload is just the generic image thumbnail.

```
obj = #<Aws::S3::Object bucket_name="mybucket", key="test">

>> params[:file]
>> "data:image/png;base64,iVB...."

obj.put(body: params[:file], content_type: 'image/png', content_encoding: 'base64')
```

How can I upload a Base64 string to s3? I'm also open to uploading as bytes if that's more straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the following code

```
file = params[:file]
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
obj = s3.bucket('my_bucket').object("my_path").upload_file(file.tempfile)
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get it to work with `put`, instead of `upload_file`. `put` makes more sense, since you are trying to upload an image encoded as a base64 data uri string.

Assuming your data uri string looks like:

```
string = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,<base_64_string>'
```

The key is to decode the `<base_64_string>` part and send it to `body` in the `put` method:

```
body = Base64.decode64(string.split(',')[1])

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']).object(key).put(body: body, acl: 'public-read', content_type: 'image/jpeg', content_encoding: 'base64')
```

This assumes you are using the the AWS Ruby library at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

Comment: Since you're decoding the data before uploading it, I would say the `content_encoding: 'base64'` it is not necessary